# Writing driver class generic for any database support

Tags: c#, .net, database, dll

For the past few days, I was working with various database such as MySQL,oracle,Ibmdb2 etc  which connect with dot net through odbc providers.

For example:

```
1)MySQL:

Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=**********;uid=**;database=**;port=***;pwd=***;"

2)oracle:

Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};server=**********;uid=**;database=**;port=***;pwd=***;"

3)Db2:

Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};server=**********;uid=**;database=**;port=***;pwd=***;"
```

now my question is

is it possible to write generic class for any database provider
as

```
Driver={My own driver};server=**********;uid=**;database=**;port=***;pwd=***;"
```

which connects every database just by changing driver name in web.config and placing that dll file in bin folder of my published web application or website project.

Comment: Yes you can, but instead of just the driver name, you will have to place the entire connectionstring in web.config since connectionstrings can vary a lot depending on db. You can then create a helper class for db actions just by implementing ISqlConnection,ISqlCommand interfaces..

Comment: @nawfal ya thanks for giving start up  since i am new to this i need to Google it and find...It will be usefull if you give me some links in order to start

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping an application database agnostic (ADO.NET vs encapsulating DB logic)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080601/keeping-an-application-database-agnostic-ado-net-vs-encapsulating-db-logic)

Answer (score 8):

To roll one of your own isn't that big a deal. Here is a basic structure of how I would implement it for bare minimum needs (you can of course expand it):

1) First create an interface specifying the basic functionalities.

```
interface IDb
{
    IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer, 
                          Func<IDataRecord, T> selector);

    int Add(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer);

    int Save(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer);

    int SaveSafely(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer);

}
```

2) Create the generic helper class which should not only implements the interface but also should be specified by the type `IDbConnection`. The class should be better (not necessarily) instantiable (not static) so that you can pass the required connection string to instantiate it.

Here is a fully lazy implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Db<T> : IDb where T : IDbConnection, new()
{
    string connectionString;

    public Db(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    IEnumerable<S> Do<R, S>(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer, 
                            Func<IDbCommand, IEnumerable<R>> actor, Func<R, S> selector)
    {
        using (var conn = new T())
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (parameterizer != null)
                    parameterizer(cmd);
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                cmd.Connection.Open();

                foreach (var item in actor(cmd))
                    yield return selector(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<S> Get<S>(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer, Func<IDataRecord, S> selector)
    {
        return Do(query, parameterizer, ExecuteReader, selector);
    }

    static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
    {
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            while (r.Read())
                yield return r;
    }

    public int Add(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        return Do(query, parameterizer, ExecuteReader, r => Convert.ToInt32(r[0])).First();
    }

    public int Save(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        return Do(query, parameterizer, ExecuteNonQuery, noAffected => noAffected).First();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
    {
        yield return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public int SaveSafely(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        // 'using' clause ensures rollback is called, so no need to explicitly rollback
        return Do(query, parameterizer, cmd => 
        {
            using (cmd.Transaction = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var noAffected = ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
                cmd.Transaction.Commit();
                return noAffected;
            }
        }, noAffected => noAffected).First();
    }
}
```

This only does the basic `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` like operations, and simple `Transaction`s. No stored procedures. The `Add` function works for inserting and retrieving the last inserted id and likes. It was crazy of me to have made things lazy and to have used just one core execution function `Do` (which is called for various db actions), and that is why `Do` looks complicated, but its very DRY. Ideally its better to be separated. You can rid of `Linq` too.

3) Lastly provide static wrapper `Db` with no generic constraints around the instantiable `Db` class so that you don't have to keep passing the `T` parameter every time to do a db query. For instance like this:

```
public static class Db
{
    static IDb db = GetDbInstance();

    static IDb GetDbInstance()
    {
        // get these two from config file or somewhere
        var connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        var driver = GetDbType();   // your logic to decide which db is being used

        // some sort of estimation of your db
        if (driver == SQLite)
            return new Db<SQLiteConnection>(connectionString);
        else if (driver == MySQL)
            return new Db<MySqlConnection>(connectionString);
        else if (driver == JET)
            return new Db<OleDbConnection>(connectionString);
        //etc

        return null;
    }

    public static void Parameterize(this IDbCommand command, string name, 
                                    object value)
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = name;
        parameter.Value = value;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string query, 
                                        Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer, 
                                        Func<IDataRecord, T> selector)
    {
        return db.Get(query, parameterizer, selector);
    }

    public static int Add(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        return db.Add(query, parameterizer);
    }

    public static int Save(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        return db.Save(query, parameterizer);
    }

    public static int SaveSafely(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer)
    {
        return db.SaveSafely(query, parameterizer);
    }
}
```

4) Now I would create an additional static function `GetDbInstance` somewhere so that it infers the right database parameters like connection string, provider type etc. Also have an extension method to ease parameterization of queries. I put both of them in the above static `Db` class but that's your choice (some people write it in the Db class itself but I prefer it outside because the functionality should be your application's).

5) Take care to have neutral queries that work on the databases you prefer.

*Or*

You can utilize [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx) under `System.Data.Common` to detect the type of `DbConnection`/provider you have. You can have just one non-generic `Db` class and do:

```
public class Db
{
    string connectionString;
    DbProviderFactory factory;

    public Db(string driver, string connectionString)
    {
        this.factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(driver);
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    //and your core function would look like
    IEnumerable<S> Do<R, S>(string query, Action<IDbCommand> parameterizer, 
                            Func<IDbCommand, IEnumerable<R>> actor, 
                            Func<R, S> selector)
    {
        using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            // and all the remaining code..
        }
    }
}
```

Your `GetDbInstance` method would look like:

```
static IDb GetDbInstance()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    string driver = GetDriver();

    return Db(driver, connectionString);
}
```

Pro: You get rid of the `if-else` style of programming and the right version of `Db` class will be instantiated depending on the provider and connection string in the config file.

Con: You need to specify the right provider/driver in the configuration file.

---

A sample query from your C# code would look like:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE id=@id AND savedStatus=@savedStatus";
var users = Db.Get(sql, cmd =>
{
    cmd.Parameterize("id", 1);
    cmd.Parameterize("savedStatus", true);
}, selector).ToArray();
```

All you have to do is call `Db.Get`, `Db.Save` etc. The function `GetDbInstance` is the key here which finds the functions in the right dlls to be called, and the helper class manages the resources well while additionally doing its task of various db operations. Such a class would avoid the hassle of opening and closing connections, freeing resources, having to include database dll namespace etc every time. This is what is called [DbAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer). You can have an [additional layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) to help DbAL communicate between various strongly typed model classes as well. I simply love the power of polymorphism via interfaces and constraints which is very very OOP! :)

Comment: @GowthamanSS I am curious to know if that helped you or not. I just wrote this out from wild imagination :) I must say I often have not found good helper classes that worked across databases..

Comment: is we need to generate seperate method for GetConnectionStringFromConfigFile,SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand,MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand,OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand in db class

Comment: No you need just one function which gets the connection string from your web.config file. You will have a key specified by some name. You have to access that key to get the connectionstring. See this link for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737393/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-read-a-connection-string-stored-in-my-web-config-file-con?rq=1. Once you read the connectionstring, you should write a logic (which is the `GetDriverFromConnectionString`) function to get which is the driver database from that connection string.

Comment: The `GetDbInstance` function will then return back the appropriate instance of your db helper class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18778/discussion-between-gowthamanss-and-nawfal)