# generic odbc class support for all database

Tags: c#, c++, .net, database, odbc

For the past few days i was working with various database with odbc connector based on my previous question on...

[Writing driver class generic for any database support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133804/writing-driver-class-generic-for-any-database-support)

i have found that all the driver class has implemented the **IDBDriver.cpp** and wrote their own connection class to support through odbc

my question is ...

1. Is it possible for me to write my own class;
2. If it succeed den just by changing the name in web.config file and placing the dll to that project can i able to handle the various connections.
3. Is there any other way...?
4. Am I proceeding in right way?

Waiting for your valuable responses

Comment: You could write a book about this. Please keep your questions simple! http://stackoverflow.com/faq for posting guidelines

Comment: @GowthamanSS My answer in your original question needs every dll to be already present in your output folder for reference while you are compiling it. Only then you will be able to write `GetDbInstance` function. Changing the db just by changing the dll from the client side may be possible if you can manually write another logic to see which dll can be loaded. But I am wondering why you need all this, its just so hacky..